# Chunk-encoded HTTP response before POST HTTP chunk-encoded request complete

Tags: java, http, chunked-encoding

I was wondering if it is possible to begin a chunk-encoded HTTP response while still receiving an HTTP request which is also chunk-encoded?

It could be useful to do some processing on-the-fly on large amount of data.

I've made some tests with [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client), [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) and Servlet-3.0's AsyncContext, but it did not work well: I can process the request on-the-fly and append calculation to the response but everything is displayed only once the request has been entirely consumed.

Do you have any idea? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly why WebSockets exist! HTTP/1.x is synchrone so it's not possibe without that.